# "You must have 1 reputation to participate on meta"

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, per-site-meta, help-center

The minimum reputation required to post on a per-site meta is a per-site setting (that defaults to 5). I don't know how many sites have this setting adjusted, but at least Code Golf and Ask Patents have the minimum reduced to 1. That leads to slightly odd messages in at least three places:

- [Help Center > What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) This has "You must have 1 reputation to participate on meta."
- [The Privilege overview](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) now lists the "you may post on meta" privilege *before* the "you may post on main" privilege.
- The [Participate in Meta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege itself contains an entire paragraph for "Why do I need 1 rep to post there?". On Ask Patents [it gets even weirder](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) where the paragraph heading still reads "...need 5 rep...".

None of these are urgent blockers, but they don't exactly improve the onboarding experience for new users who happen to discover the network through one of the sites where this privilege has been adjusted.

Comment: Interesting, http://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta have 1 rep required, but reads 5 down below...

Comment: As a side note could the help centre make up its mind whether one "participates in meta" or "participates on meta"? :)

Comment: @nicael That page is a global page that is inherited over all sites unless someone creates an "override page" for it, which was done on Code Golf when the level was changed, but not on any other sites. The "5" is a part of the text and not a variable. -- Aside: Currently the only sites where it is set to 1 are Code Golf, Ask Patents, and Stack Overflow in Japanese.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Code Golf already had an override page set up for the privilege page, I went ahead and just removed the entire last paragraph and heading, because none of that information is really relevant or useful (mostly just confusing) on a site where the privilege level is set to 1.

As far as the "What is meta?" help center article, I'm more reluctant to create an override for that page just to remove the one sentence. It's not nearly as confusing as the text on the privilege page was, and overriding pages creates a bit of a hassle for us in the future in that any changes we make will no longer get pushed to that article in the future - we have to go manually update it with the new information.

The privilege page is unlikely to ever be updated again as it's pretty straight-forward, so overriding it isn't a big deal. The help center article, though, has a much higher chance of receiving further edits and the trade-off of removing that one line versus not receiving any future updates to the article automatically is probably not a very fair trade-off.

Regarding the ordering on the list of privileges - the list of privileges is just meant to be a "this is all the things you can do once you reach this reputation level." So at 1 reputation, you can both create posts and participate on meta. Which order they appear in there is really not at all important.

Comment: I understand that the privileges at the same level are essentially unordered, and it's not a big deal. But still, a new user who sees that list will immediately notice that it's generally ordered from bottom to top so that's the most likely order they'd read them in. It would be a minor UX improvement, but I think it would be an improvement. ;)

Comment: @animuson I discovered something a bit weird [here](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1383/16670). That site [requires a rep of 5](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) to 'participate on Meta", yet the user wrote an answer. They appear to have 13 rep on Meta but only 1 on Main.